# another mass assignment error with nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm not sure why I'm still receiving this mass assignment error when trying to update boolean attributes on a user's positions with checkboxes (the boolean attribute is "is_visible"):

Here is the mass assignment error:

```
'Can't mass-assign protected attributes: position'
```

A User has_many Positions. A Position has the attribute "is_visible", which is boolean.

You'll notice I'm including "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in my user model. I'm also including in my user model "positions_attributes" as an accessible attribute.

An excerpt from my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :position_ids, :positions_attributes

has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions

end
```

And my position model:

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :is_visible

  belongs_to :user  
end
```

Excerpt from my view:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% @positions.present? and @positions.each do |position| %>
    <%= f.fields_for position do |p| %>
      <%= p.check_box :is_visible %>
    <% end %>
    Make this positions visible
<% end %>
```

And now from my users controller:

```
  def edit_profile
    @user = current_user
    @preferred_venue = @user.preferred_venues.last if @user.preferred_venues
    @positions = @user.positions
    @educations = @user.educations
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile saved"
      redirect_to @user
    end

  end
```

Would appreciate any feedback/help. Thanks!

Comment: looks like there is some error in form , params should have position_attributes key instead of position

Comment: i thought that may have been the problem but i'm not sure how to pass it through the form?

Comment: Instead of `position_ids` try just `position`